# radio button alignment

Tags: html

I am using radio buttons, but I am not sure how to align them how I want.  I want them to be on the same line like this :

```
Option 1 o   Option 2 o
```

But they appear like this :

```
Option 1 o
Option 2 o
```

Here is my HTML, can anybody advise?

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="lblMeterName" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Input/Output Group :
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="Yes"/> Yes
                        <input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="No"/> No
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="dialogButton" name="dialogButton" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Increase the width of the td to suit.

Answer (score 2):

Give your radio buttons and labels a class as follows:

```
<input type="radio" id="radioYes" class="inline-radio" name="radioGroup" value="Yes" />
<label for="radioYes" class="inline-radio">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="radioNo" class="inline-radio" name="radioGroup" value="No" />
<label for="radioNo" class="inline-radio">No</label>
```

Then apply the following CSS:

```
.inline-radio {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is an improvement over the *float* method because float often requires additional semantics to prevent undesired rendering, whereas inline-block does not.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a table like this:

```
                <td>
                  <table><tr><td>
                    <input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="Yes"/> Yes
                  </td><td>
                    <input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="No"/> No
                  </td></tr></table>
                </td>
```

This gives you the most flexibility concerning space in between or alignment with parent object.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap input and text into div and set float css property for div.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions for this:

1. You could wrap another table around the radiobuttons and add each one to a table cell.
2. Add a `<br/>` after each option.
3. You could float the radiobuttons.
4. You could add a `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` to the radiobuttons.

**I would prefer wrapping both the radiobutton and it's label in a `<label>` tag and applying `float`, since this would make the label clickable as well and provide you with more flexibility:**

```
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="Yes"/> Yes</label>
<label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="No"/> No</label>
```

And the CSS:

```
label.radio-label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Wrapping the RadioButtons in a label is a nice trick, and adding a margin sorts the spacing out - this worked great for me, I would recommend this method for increased functionality, and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Add non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` between radio buttons;

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="Yes"/> Yes</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="No"/> No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan=2><input type="button" id="dialogButton" name="dialogButton" value="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This will not work as expected because the other rows have only one cell each.

Comment: Did you notice 'colspan=2' thing?